# Hibernate: Map String to TEXT instead of VARCHAR

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I'm currently working on an assigement for a class. The Idea is to build a simple Twitter-like Back- and Frontend. For this projekt  we got a prebuild projekt with three maven modules:

- buisness (the actual API)
- persistence (the models)
- presentation (the Website)

This project uses h2 as a DB for hibernate to make development easy.
The prebuild stuff works pretty nice, but for your own service I defined this Model of a Post:

```java
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

import javax.json.bind.annotation.JsonbDateFormat;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Data
public class DBPost extends DBIdentified {

    private String message;
    private String author;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonbDateFormat(value = JsonbDateFormat.TIME_IN_MILLIS)
    private Date creationDate;

    public DBPost() {
    }

}
```

DBIdentified:

```java
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class DBIdentified {

    private long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

StartupBean:

```java
@PostConstruct
    public void startup() {

        final DBPost firstPost = this.entityManager.find(DBPost.class, 1L);

        // only initialize once
        if (firstPost == null) {
            final DBPost post = new DBPost();

            post.setUrl("https://dl.gitea.io/gitea/1.8.2/");
            post.setAuthor("Gitea");
            post.setUrgent(false);
            post.setVersion("1.8.2");
            post.setCreationDate(new Date());
            post.setMessage("BUGFIXES\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "    Fix possbile mysql invalid connnection error (#7051) (#7071)\n" +
                    "    Handle invalid administrator username on install page (#7060) (#7063)\n" +
                    "    Disable arm7 builds (#7037) (#7042)\n" +
                    "    Fix default for allowing new organization creation for new users (#7017) (#7034)\n" +
                    "    SearchRepositoryByName improvements and unification (#6897) (#7002)\n" +
                    "    Fix u2f registrationlist ToRegistrations() method (#6980) (#6982)\n" +
                    "    Allow collaborators to view repo owned by private org (#6965) (#6968)\n" +
                    "    Use AppURL for Oauth user link (#6894) (#6925)\n" +
                    "    Escape the commit message on issues update (#6901) (#6902)\n" +
                    "    Fix regression for API users search (#6882) (#6885)\n" +
                    "    Handle early git version's lack of get-url (#7065) (#7076)\n" +
                    "    Fix wrong init dependency on markup extensions (#7038) (#7074)\n");

            this.entityManager.persist(post);
        }
    }
```

When I try to insert a Post in the DB (in a Bean of the buisness module) I get this error message:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Value too long for column "MESSAGE VARCHAR(255)": "STRINGDECODE('BUGFIXES\n\n    Fix possbile mysql invalid connnection error (#7051) (#7071)\n    Handle invalid administrator use... (790)"; SQL statement:
```

I guess I need to change the type of message in the DB to something like `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT`.

But all these ways to annotate `private String message` failed:

- `@Type(type="text")`
- `@Column(length= Integer.MAX_VALUE)`
- `@Column(columnDefinition="CLOB")`
- `@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")`
- `@Column(length=65535, columnDefinition="Text")`
- `@Lob`

Could the problem be with the different modules and that the persistence module gets included in the buisness module? Or am I simply doing something wrong with regards to hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I got the answer:

In `DBIdentified` the getter was annotated and in `DBPost` the field was annotated. Mixing of field and getter annotations does not work, because hibernate will search for the @Id annotation and assume everything to be like it.

so the fix was

`DBIdentified`:

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public class DBIdentified {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is the annotation you need :

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
```

Comment: This didn't work either, I added it to the List of tested variants

Comment: What was the outcome whit this annoation?

Comment: can you try this @DerMolly : 

@Column(length = 65535,columnDefinition="Text")

Comment: @SimonMartinelli `ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) Value too long for column "MESSAGE VARCHAR(255)": "STRINGDECODE('BUGFIXES\n\n    Fix possbile mysql invalid connnection error (#7051) (#7071)\n    Handle invalid administrator use... (790)"; SQL statement:`

Comment: @Macanga same Problem. same Message.

Comment: Are you sure that your database tables are recreated after you changed the type?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli is right. You may need recreate database tables. If it does not have data yet can you change 
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> in persistence.xml to 
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />

Comment: The DB is H2 and gets newly created every time I start the software